# How to correctly use "Diff with previous version"?

Tags: tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I use TortoiseGit and at work TortoiseSVN.

Most of the time, when I modify a file, and select the option "Diff with previous version" it doesn't compare to latest file.

If I'm correct I though it would compare my copy with latest commit, but it doesn't seem to do so.

Is there a special way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Diff with previous version" compares the current state of the file to the previous committed state (i.e., `HEAD~1`). To see the changes to the latest commit just use "Diff".

Comment: wow can't believe answer was so simple. However might be language barrier, but I don't understand what is the difference between previous committed state and latest commit?

Comment: "previous committed state" = commit before the latest commit, i.e., `HEAD~1`

Comment: aaaaaaah so simple. Wow still can hardly believe I've been unable to find a solution for so long. Thanks a lot, you have no idea how it troubled me for the past 2 months!

Comment: Any idea on how to make this more obvious? Have you looked in the TortoiseGit manual?

Comment: Must admit not, I though I had a connection problems or something... I was so convinced I was having the correct option that I didn't look in this direction. Still not an expert of SVN and those stuff. Maybe the term previous version may be confusing to newbies. But I only have myself to blame.